# How to use the AndroidTestCase file?

Tags: android, unit-testing

I'm working on some stuff and some nice guy give me these [link](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/cts/+/jb-mr2-release/tests/tests/media/src/android/media/cts/EncoderTest.java). It is an AndroidTestCase file. I've done some seach, it seems that this has something to do with the TestSuit. I also read stuff about the android test frame. But there is no clear information about how could I build a test based on this AndroidTest file. Can anyone give me a hint?

Thank you!

Comment: Which IDE are you using? Please provide more specifics about what you have written and what is not working.